# Dojo spinwheelslot is stuck on returning to app

Tags: ios, xcode, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a worklight app with a dojo spinwheelslot in it.

The issue is that the spinwheelslot does not seem to work well after a user returns to the app. Here is how it happens...

1. I open the app and the spinwheelslot works fine to select values and move on to next page.
2. On the next page we have 2 links which open InAppBrowser to take users to websites. On closing the Inappbrowser and returning to the spinwheel page, the spin action is kind of jerky and it also stops in between values (not moving to one specific option). The option select is not working as expected due to this.
   Any clues what could be causing this?

1 possibility is a recent upgrade to xcode 6.0.  This spinwheel has been working before for a few months. We upgraded to xcode 6 from 5.0 very recently. That could be the starting point for this issue but I am not sure. I have reverted all my other updates since then but with no luck. Adding to the confusion is the fact that the spinwheel works fine on initial load but had problems on returning from InappBrowser.

This is a hybrid worklight app and this issue does not seem to occur on android part but only on iphone/ipad testing.

Code snippets:

**For spinwheel initialization**

```
   var CRLSContainer = dojo.byId("CountryOrRegionAndLanguageSelectContainer");
   var CRLSWidget = null;

   if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() != 'ipad') {
       CRLSWidget = new dojox.mobile.SpinWheel({
           id:"spin1",
           style:{marginLeft:"10px", marginRight:"10px"}});
   } else {
       CRLSWidget = new dojox.mobile.SpinWheel({
           id:"spin1",
           style:{marginLeft:"auto", marginRight:"auto", fontSize:"1.5em", width:"80%"}});

   CRLSWidget.placeAt(CRLSContainer);
   CRLSWidget.startup();

   var CRLSSlot = new dojox.mobile.SpinWheelSlot({
       id:"slot1",
       items:Messages.CRLSOptions,
       style:{textAlign:"center", width:"100%"}});

    CRLSWidget.addChild(CRLSSlot);
```

**For InappBrowser call**

```
function openExternalURL(url, currViewName) {
    if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() === 'android') {
        dijit.registry.byId(currViewName).performTransition("externalWebpageContainerView", 1, "slide");

        openWebViewOverlay(url);
    } else {
        window.open("blankWithSpinnyRedirectFunction.html?OpenIt&RedirectTo="+escape(url), "_blank", "toolbarposition=top,location=no,closebuttoncaption="+Messages.CloseButtonCaption);
    }
}
```

Update : I managed to fix this issue by adding the below function to CDVMainViewController.m under iphone native

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
      CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
      viewBounds.origin.y = 19;
      viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 19;
      self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
  }
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  }

Comment: Can you provide some code or example project that has just a skeleton spinwheelslot and inappbrowser implementations that reproduce this the issue?

Comment: Idan,   below is the code where the spinwheel widget is initiated.

Comment: Add it to the question body...

Comment: BTW, which version of Worklight? each version provides a different Dojo library version. Also which iOS version?

Comment: Worklight version is 6.2.0-20140918-1910. The issue is on target iOS 7. I have the same issue on my iphone running iOS 8

Comment: Hi Idan, did you get a chance to check my comments please ?

Comment: I could not. I asked the Dojo team to take a look; hopefully something will come out of that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was incorrectly posted into the question body:

> Update : I managed to fix this issue by adding the below function to
>   CDVMainViewController.m under iphone native
>
> ```
> (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
>     if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
>        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds]; viewBounds.origin.y = 19;
>        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 19;
>        self.webView.frame = viewBounds; 
>     } 
>     [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
> }
> ```